# How do I get the background color of a page in my google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a simple experimental google chrome extension that, on the press of a button, gets the background color of whatever page you are on and changes the color of the button to that color. E.g. if you are on a page with a black background, the color of the button changes to black when you press it.

I have written the following javascript code, where changeColor refers to the button in the html file

```
let changeColor = document.getElementById("changeColor");

function updateColor() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get("color", ({ color }) => {
        changeColor.style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
}

updateColor()

changeColor.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        function: storePageBackgroundColor,
    });

    updateColor()
});

function storePageBackgroundColor() {
    newColor = document.body.style.backgroundColor
    chrome.storage.sync.set({"color": newColor});
}
```

now when I press the button once it does nothing and when I press it a second time it changes the buttons color to grey regardless of what page I'm on. I'd like to know what mistake(s) I have made and what I need to do to make the button work as intended. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chrome` API methods that return a Promise or can accept a callback are asynchronous, so the work is performed after the current synchronously running code completes, meaning that you're calling `updateColor` too early.

Note that you don't need storage for this task: simply pass the result via executeScript:

```js
const changeColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');
changeColor.onclick = updateColor;
updateColor();

async function updateColor() {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    func: () => getComputedStyle(document.body).backgroundColor,
  });
  changeColor.style.backgroundColor = result;
}
```

Another possible problem is that your `<script>` tag is in `<head>`, so it runs before the button element is added to DOM. You can either move the script tag right before the closing `</body>` tag or add `defer` attribute e.g. `<script src=popup.js defer></script>`.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have an answer , but if I were you , I would do this by initializing css considering it is the foundation of looks of the page. (a suggestion)

Comment: It would certainly minimize the complexity of the code

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this, could you elaborate further?

Comment: The meaning is that css has specific commands that change the color of the background of the both the button and the page . Javascript in my opinion should only prioritize the function of the skeleton in the code and css would take on the styling . To put it in an example , css is the cloths and features of a person while javascript is the nervous system and the muscle. It would be much easier with css in the code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).